# c, macro, necesairly uints for bit numbers

Tags: c, macros

I have a macro that supposed to return necessarily uint's for certain number of bits. I use a macro because this is the size of a static array. Recently, I tried to use on 16 bit system and failed:

```
#define LCD_PIXEL_PER_CHAR    5
#define LCD_CHAR_PER_LINE 16
#define    BITMAP_SIZE        ((LCD_PIXEL_PER_CHAR * LCD_CHAR_PER_LINE)/(sizeof(int)*8)+1)
```

Now for 32 bit system, my 80 bits fits in 3 uints and some remainder.
But on 16 bit, 80 divides exactly by 16 = 5 uints and my macro return 6. Obvious, the +1 is wrong and should be redesigned.

Someone has a clever fix? Thanks

Comment: your `8` should be a `CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a check for exact fit inside a conditional expression:

```
#define BITMAP_SIZE \
  (  (LCD_PIXEL_PER_CHAR * LCD_CHAR_PER_LINE) / (sizeof(int) * 8) \
   + ((LCD_PIXEL_PER_CHAR * LCD_CHAR_PER_LINE) % (sizeof(int) * 8) ? 1 : 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you get the result of a division by `n` rounded up if you add `n - 1` before dividing. In your case:

```
#define INT_BITS (sizeof(int) * 8)
#define BITMAP_SIZE ( (LCD_PIXEL_PER_CHAR * LCD_CHAR_PER_LINE + INT_BITS - 1) / INT_BITS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, for the sake of speed, just test whether the 80 bits can be divided by the number of bits of an integer:

```
#define LCD_PIXEL_PER_CHAR 5
#define LCD_CHAR_PER_LINE 16    
#define LINE_BITS (LCD_PIXEL_PER_CHAR*LCD_CHAR_PER_LINE)
#define INT_BITS (sizeof(int)<<3)
#define BITMAP_SIZE (LINE_BITS/INT_BITS+((LINE_BITS&(INT_BITS-1))|(INT_BITS-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

After several days, I found a elegant solution in linux kernel:

```
/* How many bits in an unsigned int */
#define BitsPerInt (8 * sizeof(unsigned int))

/* howmany(a,b) : how many elements of size y needed to hold all of x */
#define howmany(x, y) (((x)+((y)-1))/(y))

/* How many unsigned int of n bits */
#define IntsPerBits(n) howmany(n, BitsPerInt)
```

So the array can be dimensioned quite easily:

```
#define     BITMAP_SIZE     IntsPerBits(LCD_PIXEL_PER_CHAR * LCD_CHAR_PER_LINE)
```